# Django - Join 2 Models in Query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    employer = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

How to write a query to retrieve all the Phone objects where `Phone.number = 945678987` and `Person.employer = 'xyz'`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

["Lookups that span relationships"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
Phone.objects.filter(number=u'945678987', person__employer=u'xyz')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Phone.objects.filter(number='945678987', person__employer='xyz')
```